# How to get rid of a jaggy ImageView border when scaling down a big image?

Tags: swift, uikit, imageview, storyboard, contentmode

I have a bunch of round Images. They are in `png` with a `512x512` size. I took them from [Flaticon](https://www.flaticon.com/packs/countrys-flags).

To display images in a `tableView` I use `imageView` with a `45x45px` size and Content Mode as `Aspect Fit`. Images put in a project `assets.xcassets` folder with a Scale property as `Single Scale`.

When images displayed by a `tableView` a jaggy border is visible in every image:

[image]

And its visible without zooming in:

[image]

Is it a problem with source images? How to make the image border smooth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with an image that you have added.
Please use a normal image and give corner radius to image view as below

```
self.imageFlag.layer.cornerRadius = self.imageFlag.frame.size.height/2
```

This will resolve your issue
Below is the screenshot
[image]

Comment: Hi Ritu. Thank you for the reply! But what if I want to use already rounded image itself? Is it possible to scale it down without the jaggy border?

Comment: Hi @artexhibit, i have also used round image and it is working fine. You can use clipToBounds to image view